# Where are technical names for a field stored in orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I've had issues in the past where I cannot retrieve field values because the technical name is set to something other than what I expect. One good example would be when you create two of the same field or sometimes the technical name gets stored with spaces in it. Is there any way we can change the technical name after the field is created?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find it in the admin UI, but you can find it in the database in the table `Settings_ContentPartFieldDefinitionRecord`.